# Parallel Process Raster by Tiling?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, r-raster, terra

I have a raster file (TIFF) characterizing ocean depths. I want to split this raster into multiple tiles that can each be processed in parallel to reclassify depths deeper than 7m as NA. Then later I would like to recombine these files into one larger tiff. Is this possible or practical?

My current code reclassifies depths for the entire TIFF file and takes too long to accomplish. I'd really love to learn how to do this in parallel but am not able to find a good guide.

This is my current code:

```
Hawaii_Bathymetry <- raster(here("2_output", "modified_rasters", "Hawaii_Bathymetry.tif"))

#### Save depths from -7 to 2 m
vals <- cbind(-Inf, -7, NA) #Replace all elevations less than -7 m with NA

Bathymetry_reclass <- reclassify(Hawaii_Bathymetry, rcl = vals)

vals <- cbind(1, Inf, NA) #Replace all elevations more than 1 m with NA
Bathymetry_reclass <- reclassify(Bathymetry_reclass, rcl = vals)

writeRaster(Bathymetry_reclass, file=here("2_output", "modified_rasters", "Hawaii_Bathymetry_-7_to_1.tif"), format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I was not able to find a tiling command that could do this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an approach. Note that in this toy example, the overhead of parallel computation makes it not worth it. However, the idea is to break your raster into tiles, reclassify each tile in parallel, and then merge them all together. Another note: SpatRast cannot be serialized, so you must `wrap` each tile and un`wrap` them before merging.

```
library(terra)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
vals <- cbind(300, Inf, NA) #Replace all elevations less than -7 m with NA
x <- rast(ncol=4,nrow=4,extent=ext(r))
tl <- makeTiles(r,x,overwrite=T,extend=T)

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(length(tl))
registerDoParallel(cl)

reclassed <- foreach(i = 1:length(tl),
                .packages = "terra") %dopar% {
                  crp <- wrap(terra::classify(rast(tl[i]),rcl=vals))
                  return(crp)
                }
stopCluster(cl)

merged <- do.call(terra::merge,lapply(reclassed,terra::rast))
plot(merged)
```